# run shell script from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, bash, shell

I want to use Eclipse to run build scripts (on Ubuntu).

I use make tool to do it like this:

```
build_android:
chmod 755 "./build_android.sh"
./build_android.sh
```

I use make tool to launch scripts but I get "permission denied" on some strings, like

```
./build_android.sh: 19: function: Permission denied
```

on

```
NDK=/home/student/devtools/android-ndk-r8d
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86

function build_one
{
./configure --target-os=linux \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-cross-compile \
#and so on...
}
```

Why can it be and what solution is to launch scripts in Eclipse.

P.S. Why do I want it? I think it would be more productive to launch scripts in several clicks and also see the script output formatted in the console view of the environment.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is line 19? You may not have permissions to do something in a certain directory you are working on.

Comment: "function build_one" is line 19. how do i get permissions for makefile? when i run the script from the terminal it does work, without sudo even.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the eclipse plugin:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/

Answer (score 0):

Probably Eclipse uses some other shell to execute the script, one that cannot define functions. Put a line `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the script.

Comment: Thanks. Actually now I'm not busy with this problem, but once I get back to it I'll check it out.